# Celery, Django and Scrapy: error importing from django app

Tags: python, django, scrapy, celery, django-celery

I'm using `celery` (and `django-celery`) to allow a user to launch periodic scrapes through the django admin. This is part of a larger project but I've boiled the issue down to a minimal example.

Firstly, celery/celerybeat are running daemonized. If instead I run them with `celery -A evofrontend worker -B -l info` from my django project dir then **I get no issues** weirdly.

When I run celery/celerybeat as daemons however then I get a strange import error:

```
[2016-01-06 03:05:12,292: ERROR/MainProcess] Task evosched.tasks.scrapingTask[e18450ad-4dc3-47a0-b03d-4381a0e65c31] raised unexpected: ImportError('No module named myutils',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lee/Desktop/pyco/evo-scraping-min/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lee/Desktop/pyco/evo-scraping-min/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "evosched/tasks.py", line 35, in scrapingTask
    cs = CrawlerScript('TestSpider', scrapy_settings)
  File "evosched/tasks.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.crawler = CrawlerProcess(scrapy_settings)
  File "/home/lee/Desktop/pyco/evo-scraping-min/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 209, in __init__
    super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
  File "/home/lee/Desktop/pyco/evo-scraping-min/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 115, in __init__
    self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
  File "/home/lee/Desktop/pyco/evo-scraping-min/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 296, in _get_spider_loader
    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
  File "/home/lee/Desktop/pyco/evo-scraping-min/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 30, in from_settings
    return cls(settings)
  File "/home/lee/Desktop/pyco/evo-scraping-min/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 21, in __init__
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "/home/lee/Desktop/pyco/evo-scraping-min/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "retail/spiders/Retail_spider.py", line 16, in <module>
ImportError: No module named myutils
```

i.e. the spider is having issues importing from the django project app despite adding the relevant things to syslog, and doing `django.setup()`.

My hunch is that this may be caused by a " circular import" during initialization, but I'm not sure (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/) for notes on same error)

**Celery daemon config**

For completeness the celeryd and celerybeat configuration scripts are:

```
# /etc/default/celeryd
CELERYD_NODES="worker1"

CELERY_BIN="/home/lee/Desktop/pyco/evo-scraping-min/venv/bin/celery"

CELERY_APP="evofrontend"
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="evofrontend.settings"

CELERYD_CHDIR="/home/lee/Desktop/pyco/evo-scraping-min/evofrontend"

CELERYD_OPTS="--concurrency=1"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
CELERYD_USER="lee"
CELERYD_GROUP="lee"

CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
```

and

```
# /etc/default/celerybeat 
CELERY_BIN="/home/lee/Desktop/pyco/evo-scraping-min/venv/bin/celery"

CELERY_APP="evofrontend"
CELERYBEAT_CHDIR="/home/lee/Desktop/pyco/evo-scraping-min/evofrontend/"

# Django settings module
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="evofrontend.settings"
```

They are largely based on the [the generic ones](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html), with the Django settings thrown in and using the celery bin in my virtualenv rather than system.

I'm also using the `init.d` scripts which are [the generic ones](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html).

**Project structure**

As for the project: it lives at `/home/lee/Desktop/pyco/evo-scraping-min`. All files under it have ownership `lee:lee`.
The dir contains both a Scrapy (evo-retail) and Django (evofrontend) project that live under it and the complete tree structure looks like

```
├── evofrontend
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── evofrontend
│   │   ├── celery.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   ├── evosched
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── myutils.py
│   │   └── tasks.py
│   └── manage.py
└── evo-retail
    └── retail
        ├── logs
        ├── retail
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── settings.py
        │   └── spiders
        │       ├── __init__.py
        │       └── Retail_spider.py
        └── scrapy.cfg
```

**Django project relevant files**

Now the relevant files: the `evofrontend/evofrontend/celery.py` looks like

```
# evofrontend/evofrontend/celery.py
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'evofrontend.settings')

from django.conf import settings

app = Celery('evofrontend')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

The potentially relevant settings from the Django settings file, `evofrontend/evofrontend/settings.py` are

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir))

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'djcelery',
    'evosched',
)

# Celery settings
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost//'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/London'
CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD = 1  # Each worker is killed after one task, this prevents issues with reactor not being restartable
# Use django-celery backend database
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
# Set periodic task
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"
```

The `tasks.py` in the scheduling app, `evosched`, looks like (it just launches the Scrapy spider using the relevant settings after changing dir)

```
# evofrontend/evosched/tasks.py
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import shared_task
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
import os
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from django.conf import settings as django_settings


class CrawlerScript(object):
    def __init__(self, spider, scrapy_settings):
        self.crawler = CrawlerProcess(scrapy_settings)
        self.spider = spider  # just a string

    def run(self, **kwargs):
        # Pass the kwargs (usually command line args) to the crawler
        self.crawler.crawl(self.spider, **kwargs)
        self.crawler.start()


@shared_task
def scrapingTask(**kwargs):

    logger.info("Start scrape...")

    # scrapy.cfg file here pointing to settings...
    base_dir = django_settings.BASE_DIR
    os.chdir(os.path.join(base_dir, '..', 'evo-retail/retail'))
    scrapy_settings = get_project_settings()

    # Run crawler
    cs = CrawlerScript('TestSpider', scrapy_settings)
    cs.run(**kwargs)
```

The `evofrontend/evosched/myutils.py` simply contains (in this min example):

```
 # evofrontend/evosched/myutils.py
 SCRAPY_XHR_HEADERS = 'SOMETHING'
```

**Scrapy project relevant files**

In the complete Scrapy project the settings file looks like

```
# evo-retail/retail/retail/settings.py
BOT_NAME = 'retail'

import os
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

SPIDER_MODULES = ['retail.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'retail.spiders'
```

and (in this min example) the spider is just

```
# evo-retail/retail/retail/spiders/Retail_spider.py
from scrapy.conf import settings as scrapy_settings
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request
import sys
import django
import os
import posixpath
SCRAPY_BASE_DIR = scrapy_settings['PROJECT_ROOT']
DJANGO_DIR = posixpath.normpath(os.path.join(SCRAPY_BASE_DIR, '../../../', 'evofrontend'))
sys.path.insert(0, DJANGO_DIR)
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", 'evofrontend.settings')
django.setup()
from evosched.myutils import SCRAPY_XHR_HEADERS

class RetailSpider(Spider):

    name = "TestSpider"

    def start_requests(self):
        print SCRAPY_XHR_HEADERS
        yield Request(url='http://www.google.com', callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        print response.url
        return []
```

**EDIT:**

I discovered through lots of trial and error that if the app I'm trying to import from is in my `INSTALLED_APPS` django setting, then it fails with the import error, but if I remove the app from there then no longer do I get the import error (e.g. removing `evosched` from `INSTALLED_APPS` then the import in the spider goes through fine...). Obviously not a solution, but may be a clue.

**EDIT 2**

I put a print of `sys.path` immediately before the failing import in the spider, the result was

```
/home/lee/Desktop/pyco/evo-scraping-min/evofrontend/../evo-retail/retail 
/home/lee/Desktop/pyco/evo-scraping-min/venv/lib/python2.7
/home/lee/Desktop/pyco/evo-scraping-min/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/home/lee/Desktop/pyco/evo-scraping-min/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/home/lee/Desktop/pyco/evo-scraping-min/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old  
/home/lee/Desktop/pyco/evo-scraping-min/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/home/lee/Desktop/pyco/evo-scraping-min/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/home/lee/Desktop/pyco/evo-scraping-min/evofrontend 
/home/lee/Desktop/pyco/evo-scraping-min/evo-retail/retail`
```

**EDIT 3**

If I do `import evosched` then `print dir(evosched)`, I see "tasks" and if I choose to include such a file, I can also see "models", so importing from models would actually be possible. I don't however see " myutils". Even `from evosched import myutils` fails and also fails if the statement is put in a function below rather than as a global(I thought this might route out a circular import issue...). The direct `import evosched` works...possibly `import evosched.utils` will work. Not yet tried...

Answer (score 0):

It seems the celery daemon is running using the system's python and not the `python` binary inside the virtualenv. You need to use

```
# Python interpreter from environment. 
ENV_PYTHON="$CELERYD_CHDIR/env/bin/python"
```

As mentioned [here](https://ask.github.io/celery/cookbook/daemonizing.html#example-django-configuration-using-virtualenv) to tell celeryd to run using the python inside the virtualenv.

Comment: Darn, I thought you were on to something with that, but I added it in `/etc/default/celeryd` after setting `CELERYD_CHDIR` and then restarted everything and I'm still getting the same import error. Just to double check this wasn't the problem I also did a  `print 'Python bin is %s' % sys.executable` before the problematic import line and in the celery logs I see "Python bin is /home/lee/Desktop/pyco/evo-scraping-min/venv/bin/python"

Comment: I discovered through lots of trial and error that if the app I'm trying to import from is in my `INSTALLED_APPS` django setting, then it fails with the import error, but if I remove the app from there then no longer do I get the import error (e.g. removing `evosched` from `INSTALLED_APPS` then the import in the spider goes through fine...)

Comment: Som it seems that celery is unable to find only a specific app in your dir structure. If you remove `evosched` then `evosched/tasks.py` will never be used and so python will never try to import `retail/spiders/Retail_spider.py`. But this is kinda useless because now the scrapy app does nothing.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it with another module to verify (rather than evosched)...the same problem occurs for any django app in the project if that app is listed in the INSTALLED_APPS and I try and import from it in the spider

Comment: I put a print of the `sys.path` before the failed import (after adding the app back to django `INSTALLED_APPS`), and I'll add to the OP.

Comment: Could you check the `DJANGO_DIR` which you're adding to the `sys.path` ? You could do this by adding a `raise AssertionError(DJANGO_DIR)` - this will help in checking whether the directory is correct inside celeryd. (As it will throw an error with the directory as a message)

Comment: For the `DJANGO_DIR` the result was `AssertionError: /home/lee/Desktop/pyco/evo-scraping-min/evofrontend`

Comment: It's weird that this works fine with the manual command, but not the daemons. It's weird that the module being in `INSTALLED_APPS` causes the break.

Comment: Does the application work if you remove it from INSTALLED_APPS ? I had assumed it just didn't load anything and it was essentially a dummy app.

Comment: In the real app, I need the django app to be a real django app yes.

Comment: I've got a feeling this is going to be to do with import loops...see the note on this same error here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/